# tableview/tableviewcell weird behavior with labels.isHidden

Tags: swift, uitableview, realm

I have a game where I want to show the history in a tableview.
The game can be played exact with 4 players. The results of winners/losers can vary between 2w/2l, 3w/1l or 1w/3l.

Therefore I created a custom cell as a XIB, where I placed 3 labels (each for winner&losers, so 6 labels in total) in a stackview and I hide always 2 by default. Then, when I have more than one winner/loser I will unhide them and set the names.

But somehow my code does things I don't understand. I tried to debug my code but if it runs slowly it seems to be okay. I don't get it.

My `Players` struct is just a small part of my Realm object. Also the whole `allPlayers` array is just dummy data, usually I fetch it from realm.

```
struct Players {
    let round: Int
    let name: String
    let winner: Bool
    let loser: Bool
}
```

So I have setup my `ViewController` standardly as follows:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    let allPlayers: [Players] = [Players(round: 1, name: "Mike", winner: false, loser: true),     // Round 1 2:2
                                 Players(round: 1, name: "Peter", winner: false, loser: true),
                                 Players(round: 1, name: "Tim", winner: true, loser: false),
                                 Players(round: 1, name: "Levi", winner: true, loser: false),
                                 Players(round: 2, name: "Mike", winner: false, loser: true),     // Round 2 1:3
                                 Players(round: 2, name: "Peter", winner: false, loser: true),
                                 Players(round: 2, name: "Tim", winner: false, loser: true),
                                 Players(round: 2, name: "Levi", winner: true, loser: false),
                                 Players(round: 3, name: "Mike", winner: true, loser: false),     // Round 3 3:1
                                 Players(round: 3, name: "Peter", winner: true, loser: false),
                                 Players(round: 3, name: "Tim", winner: true, loser: false),
                                 Players(round: 3, name: "Levi", winner: false, loser: true),
                                 Players(round: 4, name: "Mike", winner: false, loser: true),     // Round 4 2:2
                                 Players(round: 4, name: "Peter", winner: false, loser: true),
                                 Players(round: 4, name: "Tim", winner: true, loser: false),
                                 Players(round: 4, name: "Levi", winner: true, loser: false),
                                 Players(round: 5, name: "Mike", winner: false, loser: true),     // Round 5 1:3
                                 Players(round: 5, name: "Peter", winner: false, loser: true),
                                 Players(round: 5, name: "Tim", winner: false, loser: true),
                                 Players(round: 5, name: "Levi", winner: true, loser: false),
                                 Players(round: 6, name: "Mike", winner: true, loser: false),     // Round 6 3:1
                                 Players(round: 6, name: "Peter", winner: true, loser: false),
                                 Players(round: 6, name: "Tim", winner: true, loser: false),
                                 Players(round: 6, name: "Levi", winner: false, loser: true),
                                 Players(round: 7, name: "Mike", winner: true, loser: false),     // Round 7 3:1
                                 Players(round: 7, name: "Peter", winner: true, loser: false),
                                 Players(round: 7, name: "Tim", winner: true, loser: false),
                                 Players(round: 7, name: "Levi", winner: false, loser: true),
                                 Players(round: 8, name: "Mike", winner: false, loser: true),     // Round 8 1:3
                                 Players(round: 8, name: "Peter", winner: false, loser: true),
                                 Players(round: 8, name: "Tim", winner: false, loser: true),
                                 Players(round: 8, name: "Levi", winner: true, loser: false),
                                 Players(round: 9, name: "Mike", winner: false, loser: true),     // Round 9 1:3
                                 Players(round: 9, name: "Peter", winner: false, loser: true),
                                 Players(round: 9, name: "Tim", winner: false, loser: true),
                                 Players(round: 9, name: "Levi", winner: true, loser: false),
                                 Players(round: 10, name: "Mike", winner: false, loser: true),     // Round 10 2:2
                                 Players(round: 10, name: "Peter", winner: false, loser: true),
                                 Players(round: 10, name: "Tim", winner: true, loser: false),
                                 Players(round: 10, name: "Levi", winner: true, loser: false),
                                 Players(round: 11, name: "Mike", winner: false, loser: true),     // Round 11 2:2
                                 Players(round: 11, name: "Peter", winner: false, loser: true),
                                 Players(round: 11, name: "Tim", winner: true, loser: false),
                                 Players(round: 11, name: "Levi", winner: true, loser: false),
                                 Players(round: 12, name: "Mike", winner: true, loser: false),     // Round 12 3:1
                                 Players(round: 12, name: "Peter", winner: true, loser: false),
                                 Players(round: 12, name: "Tim", winner: true, loser: false),
                                 Players(round: 12, name: "Levi", winner: false, loser: true)]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        let nib = UINib.init(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil)
        self.tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "winLooseCell")
    }
}
```

Because I fetch the data from Realm I made a separate class `handler` to manage the results and so I only get back arrays of names of the winners/losers.

```
class Handler {
    var winners: [String] = []
    var losers: [String] = []
    
    func getWinners(round: Int,dataBase: [Players]) -> [String] {
        // Filtercode is just boilerplate, is dunno by realm
        let filtered = dataBase.filter{ dataBase in
            return dataBase.round == round
        }
        for i in 0...filtered.count - 1 {
            if filtered[i].winner {
                winners.append(filtered[i].name)
            }
        }
        return winners
    }
    
    func getLosers(round: Int,dataBase: [Players]) -> [String] {
        // Filtercode is just boilerplate, is dunno by realm
        let filtered = dataBase.filter{ dataBase in
            return dataBase.round == round
        }
        for i in 0...filtered.count - 1{
            if filtered[i].loser {
                losers.append(filtered[i].name)
            }
        }
        return losers
    }
}
```

And of course my tableView extension to create the whole thing

```
// MARK: Extension
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (allPlayers.count / 4)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let handler = Handler()
        
        if indexPath.row == 10 {
            // do nothing - just for a debugging breakpoint
        }
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "winLooseCell") as! TableViewCell
        
        let winner = handler.getWinners(round: indexPath.row + 1, dataBase: allPlayers)
        for i in 0...winner.count - 1 {
            cell.winnerNameLabels[i].isHidden = false
            cell.winnerNameLabels[i].text = winner[i]
        }
        
        let loser = handler.getLosers(round: indexPath.row + 1, dataBase: allPlayers)
        for i in 0...loser.count - 1 {
            cell.loserNameLabels[i].isHidden = false
            cell.loserNameLabels[i].text = loser[i]
        }
        
        cell.roundLabel.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)"
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

The class for the tableViewCell

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var winnerNameLabels: [UILabel]!
    @IBOutlet var loserNameLabels: [UILabel]!
    @IBOutlet weak var roundLabel: UILabel!
}
```

and the Xib File
[image]

and for some reason after I load the simulator I get in round 11 this weird behavior

[image]

Anyone got an idea why and how I can solve this issue?

Comment: I am pretty sure the answer by @matt is correct, but, did you add a breakpoint and step through the code in this loop `for i in 0...winner.count - 1` to ensure it's iterating the correct number of times? And likewise for the looser loop? Including debugging details like that can help us narrow the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're forgetting that cells are reused. A cell that appears in a certain row can reappear later in a different row — as you scroll, for instance. Therefore you must take account of what row this is, completely, in your logic for configuring the cell.

Thus, in `cellForRowAt`, we see that your code might say

```
 cell.winnerNameLabels[i].isHidden = false
```

But at *no* time do you *ever* say

```
 cell.winnerNameLabels[i].isHidden = true
```

Therefore once you have unhidden a label for this cell, it *remains* unhidden no matter what row this cell is reused in, for the rest of the lifetime of the app.